# Access a state property within a getter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm pretty new to Vue.js and Vuex and I'm now trying to follow a tutorial to explain Vuex. Whenever I try to access the getter `messageUpperCase` it doesn't render the page anymore.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ welcome }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
    <h3>Getter: {{ messageCaps }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      welcome: "Hello world"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    message() {
      return this.$store.state.message;
    },
    messageCaps() {
      return this.$store.getter.messageUpperCase;
    }
  },
  store: {
    state: {
      message: "Hello from vuex",
      count: 0
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    getters: {
      messageUpperCase(state) {
        // return state.message.toUpperCase();
        return this.$store.state.message.toUpperCase()
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

How is it possible to access the `state.message` within the getter `messageUpperCase`?

Comment: Store is usually added separately in another file. Could you able to get the value in message directly?

Comment: That's not how you define a Vuex store. Follow this tutorial instead ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: Yes, message is displayed correctly coming from the store. @Phil I wanted to start with everything in one file so I could easily see what happens.

Comment: In order to access `this.$store`, Vuex needs to be installed as a plugin (ie `Vue.use(Vuex)`), the store created as an instance of `Vuex.Store` and then injected into your root `Vue` instance as its `store` property

Comment: Also, it may make a difference that you have a typo `this.$store.getter.messageUpperCase;` note `getter` should (I think) be `getters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the guide to add `vuex` to your project : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

You can add this where your `Vue` initiated, like this

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      message: "Hello from vuex",
      count: 0
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    getters: {
      messageUpperCase: state => {
        // return state.message.toUpperCase();
        return state.message.toUpperCase()
      }
    }
})
```

And include while initiating the `Vue` like this

```
new Vue({
    el: '#your-id',
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

Answer to your question:

```
messageUpperCase: state => {
  // return state.message.toUpperCase();
  return state.message.toUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `Vue.use(Vuex)`

Comment: Strange, it says "store is not defined". While I am perfectly capable of doing a commit on the counter `store.commit('increment')` to increase its number within `main.js`. However, when calling the computed property in `App.vue` like  `count() {return store.state.count}` it doesn't work and throws the error.

Comment: Found it, it needed to be `return this.$store.state.count;`

Comment: If you're trying to access the `store` from component, then it should be called as `this.$store.state.count`. Please update the question is it is not working.